# SAML SSO login with two different service providers and common identity provider

Tags: java, single-sign-on, saml-2.0

I want to have multiple Service provider and one common Identity provider.
Once user logged in from one SP and clicks a link of other SP link.

It should directly login to second SP.
How should i call the second SP link?

mine is IDP initiated SSO and once i have assertion data from IDP how to post it to second SP.

Comment: Did you come to any conclusion on this? I'm looking to do the same.

Comment: I was able to fix it